# LaTeX3 and \PackageError

Tags: expl3, latex3

What is the good way to display errors in the console via `\PackageError` when this command is used inside `\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff` because for the moment the spaces in the messages are not displayed (I know that is normal) ?

Comment: `~` is a space within `ExplSyntax`

Comment: Thanks a lot (take a look at your github tkz-tab )

Comment: Alain has resumed work on the tkz- files the github isn't really "mine" even though I set it up. if you report an issue there Alain should get to it at some point.

Comment: That was just a joke. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~` is a space within ExplSyntax

Comment: But it should be noted that it is not a space at the beginning of a line (and a newline is not a space either) Therefore, if you put the text over several lines you have to add the `~` at the end of the line not at the beginning of the next --- this is due to the way TeX drops newlines.